# What is the direct link to my Symfony App front page?

Tags: symfony

I know this is amateur but I have to ask this.

Basically I am modifying my `Symofony` based app and I am moving it to another server.

I have already pulled the files from my `github` repository.

I have my old files on my old server connected with the domain.

What is the direct link to the website on the new server if it is not connected to the domain?

Domain points to the server root on the old server.

What am I supposed to write to enter the website on my new server?

www.mylogin.host.com/XXXX
index.html?
app/ something?
views/indexmain.html?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
#echo phpversion(); exit;
/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
}

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    $kernel->loadClassCache(); 
}
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: This depends on the Symfony version you are using and your nginx/apache host configuration. The front controller for symfony 2.x/3.x is web/app.php and for 4.x is public/index.php

Comment: added the web/app.php since i do not really understand it

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Step 1 : Put your sources in a directory of your new  server. Step 2 : Copy paste your nginx/apache vhost from old to new server and change the root accordingly of step 1. Step 2.1 : Reload your server Step 3 : Change your DNS zone with your new server info.